# Can magnets bend electricity or lightning?

Tags: magnetic-fields

If you have a high powered magnet would it be able to repel lightning or electricity? I know that electricity has something to do with magnetism but I'm not sure if it could be attracted or repelled by magnets.

Answer (score 2):

[Charged particles moving in an electric field are deflected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force), so the answer is yes, you can bend lightning.

For an order of magnitude estimate, the formula for the force experienced is $F = B q v$, where $B$ is the magnetic field, $q$ is the charge of the particle, and $v$ is the speed at which the particle is moving. If we assume the charged particles in lightning are electrons, that they are moving at the speed of light, and we want them to move in a circular motion of radius 1 meter after they are deflected, then

$F = Bqc = ma = mc^2/r \rightarrow B = mv/qr = 1.7 \times 10^{-3} T$, which is actually not that large.

Comment: For lightning it would bend westward due to the Earth's magnetic field, but there are other forces in play so it doesn't bend circularly (the radius would be ~50m - less height than many a storm cloud)

Comment: so what is the strength of the magnet required repel the electricity? and would you be able to make electricity travel in a circle inside of a torus if the torus was magnetically charged?

Comment: @WillG I'd recommend reading either the Wikipedia article on Lorentz force, or a first-year university textbook on the same topic. Magnetic fields cannot repel electricity, only change their direction. To get circular motion, you need a uniform magnetic field. There's also no such thing as magnetic charge (at least, not yet).